# SQL where clause with composite key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, where-clause, composite-key

I'm writing custom Oracle queries to delete data from child tables in order to avoid foreign key constraint as part of a utility to clean up test data.

Let's say I've two tables - Table 1 (PK - (id1,id2)) and Table 2 (FK -(id3,id4)), where id1,id2,id3,id4 are all of type Number. Table 2 has a composite foreign key constraint on Table 1's primary key. Here is what I've right now (just selecting now, will change to delete later):

```
select (cast(t2.id3 as varchar2(30)) || ',' || cast(t2.id4 as varchar2(10)))  
as new_search from Table2 t2 where new_search in 
(select (cast(t1.id1 as varchar2(30)) || ',' || cast(t1.id2 as varchar2(10))) 
as new_search from Table1 t1 where t1.someColumn=someValue);
```

However, executing this gives me ORA-00904 NEW_SEARCH:invalid_identifier. So, my questions are:

(1) What am I doing wrong here? and
(2) Is there any better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You cannot use column aliases in where clause
2) Try this:

```
select t2.id3, t2.id4 
from Table2 t2 
where (t2.id3, t2.id4) in 
  (select t1.id1, t1.id2 
   from Table1 t1 
   where t1.someColumn=someValue
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! I was over thinking it.